# Which context is injected by roboguice by default?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice

If I use the following code:

```
@Inject
Context context;
```

then which type of context will be injected? The application or the current activity? Or something else?

I know I can force the guice to inject application context with this:

```
@Inject
Application context;
```

But can I configure the first example's injection to inject application context instead of activity?